# ¿Como exportar un script de creacion de base de datos preservando las relaciones de clave que tienen las tablas?

Tags: mysql, sql, script, mysql-workbench

Estoy generando un backup para enviar la base de datos a otra persona, pero esta se genera sin sus relaciones , he intentado lo mismo con otra base de datos y esta si preserva sus relaciones, pero solo la base que deseo exportar se exporta sin relaciones.

Comment: visualice el script manualmente y no veo por ningún lado que se exporte con sus respectivas relaciones de tablas.

Comment: ayudaría mucho si editas tu pregunta y colocas tal vez una muestra de tu backup, evitando mostrar información sensible

Comment: el script de la db es inmensa , pertenece a un erp , seria muy difícil subirla por aquí.

Answer (score 0):

En MySQL Workbench al seleccionar la base de datos de trabajo , presenta las opciones:

- Dump Estructure and Data (Extrae la estructura de la Base de datos + Los Datos)
- Dump Data Only (Solo los Datos)
- Dump Structure Only (Estructura de la Base de Datos)

Asegurate que al extraer, has seleccionado la primera opción, de lo contrario no podrás replicar la base, si has extraído solo los datos, entonces lo que puedes hacer es hacer otro backup solo de la estructura de la base luego hacer la replicación en 2 pasos, primero replicas la estructura y posteriormente cargas los datos mediante MySQL Workbench en la opción Data Import/Restore.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]